# Declaration file cannot be loaded

Tags: typescript

I want to use an enum value declared in `declarations/hoge.d.ts` file in mocha unit test, but it shows `ReferenceError: hoge is not defined` error.

My test code is like this:

```
import hello from './hello';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('Hello function', () => {
    it('should not return hoge', () => {
        const result = hello();
        expect(result).not.equal(hoge.FUGA);
    });
});
```

And the declaration file is:

```
declare enum hoge {
    HOGE,
    FUGA
}
```

tsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "files": [
        "declarations/hoge.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

The compiler looks able to find `hoge.d.ts` but cannot resolve it. Reference error happens on both VS code and running test.

Could anyone figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to import the module where hoge is defined.

Maybe add

```
import {hoge} from './hoge'
```

or

```
import {hoge} from 'hoge'
```

or maybe refer to it as `hello.hoge`. `hoge` doesn't appear to be in scope

Comment: My understanding is the value declared with `declare` keyword becomes global so can be used without importing the file as a module.

Do I really have to import the values from `d.ts` file?

Comment: Afaik, the only way to do this is to do it in the tsconfig file, but it's a bad idea in this case. If you're inventing your own language, like AssemblyScript - that's an appropriate use of that mechanism. You either need to `import`, or simply put the declare statement in the same file as your code.